# There is a small discrepancy in the docs for users-id-associated

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, documentation

The main doc page, https://api.stackexchange.com/docs, shows /users/{id}/associated while the method page, https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users, uses /users/{ids}/associated.

It's minor but it's there.

Comment: I can confirm this - a quick test reveals that the method accepts multiple account IDs though the home page would indicate that it only accepts one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest deploy fixed this.

As George pointed out, the method does take multiple account ids.